# Convergence of a sequence of integration

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

I am considering one problem and I am stuck in this step. The problem is that

What conditions on function $f(u,\epsilon)$ are required to satisfy

$$
\int_0^\epsilon f(u,\epsilon)\,du \rightarrow 0 
$$
as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$.

For example, If $f(u,\epsilon)=u \epsilon$, then above statement holds. 
But, if $f(u,\epsilon)= \frac{\sqrt{u}}{\epsilon^2}$, fails.

Comment: Are you asking for "necessary and sufficient" conditions, or will merely "sufficient" conditions do? Continuity of $f$ in both variables is clearly sufficient.

Comment: Sufficient condition: There is some $\epsilon_0 > 0$ and an integrable $g:[0,\epsilon_0]\to\mathbb R$ such that $|f(u,\epsilon)| \le g(u)$ for all $0\le u, \epsilon\le \epsilon_0$.